# Start app by hardwarekey Android Application

Tags: android, sdk, key, hardware

I just started creating apps, and now I want to know how to build something that 
helps me to start an app, by execercising a volume down/up press during the sleepmode of my phone. 
I think that it will need an OnReceive Method or something that works like a onclicklistener but i cant figure it out.

Greetings

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal way its not possible to catch your volume down/up receiver when your phone is locked(straight-forward). However here in this discussion they are trying to control volume when phone is locked via some other way - [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472195/handling-volume-change-on-android-lockscreen)

However you can launch your application when the phone is unlocked by using volume down/up event or combination using the receiver logic. You can register for "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" to receive the broadcastreceiver.

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick answer. Maybe this helps a little bit.